# Does a render happen before function in React Hooks useEffect is called?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would have thought that useEffect's first function gets called before the first render, but when I call the method below, my console.log just before the return method call gets called, then the useEffect's first parameter function gets called.

order of calls:

```
just before render return
ImageToggleOnScroll.js:8 useEffect before setInView
ImageToggleOnScroll.js:10 useEffect after setInView
```

Source:

```
import React, {useState,useRef,useEffect} from "react";

// primaryImg is black and white, secondaryImg is color
const ImageToggleOnMouseOver = ({ primaryImg, secondaryImg }) => {
    const imageRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect before setInView')
        setInView(isInView());
        console.log('useEffect after setInView')
        window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
        };
    }, []);

    const isInView = () => {
        if (imageRef.current) {
            const rect = imageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            return rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight;
        }
        return false;
    };

    const [inView, setInView] = useState(false);
    const scrollHandler = () => {
        setInView(() => {
            return isInView();
        });
    };

    console.log('just before render return')
    return (
        <img
            ref={imageRef}
            src={inView ? secondaryImg : primaryImg}
            alt="image here"
        />
    );
};

export default ImageToggleOnMouseOver;
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Effects created using `useEffect` are run after the render commit phase and hence after the render cycle. This is to make sure that no side-effects are executed during the render commit phase which might cause inconsistency

According to the documentation

> Mutations, subscriptions, timers, logging, and other side effects are
>   not allowed inside the main body of a function component (referred to
>   as React’s render phase). Doing so will lead to confusing bugs and
>   inconsistencies in the UI.
>
> The function passed to `useEffect` will run
>   after the render is committed to the screen.

`useEffect` hook can be used to replicate behavior of `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle methods for class components depending the arguments passed to the dependency array which is the second argument to useEffect and the return function from within the callback which is executed before the next effect is run or before unmount

For certain useCases such as `animations` you may make use of `useLayoutEffect` which is executed synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

Comment: Thanks @Shubham, as you say, for "certain cases".  My case is not one of them.

Comment: hi @Shubham Khatri +1. Then why does the "Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. Put the async function inside" message come up if useEffect is said to run **asynchronously**?

Answer (score 4):

According to the `useEffect` [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

So yes, it runs after the first render and each subsequent render.