# Pass parameters to another component

Tags: reactjs

How to properly pass parameter from one component to another component. In my scenario, When I console log my pass parameter to another component they have empty string first before the actual string in the last. Which is supposed to be the actual string only.

Component 1:

```
 import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
 import {dataComponent} from './include/childComponent'

 export default function Parentcomponent(props) {

    const [data, setdata] = useState('');

    function functioncalhttp(){

    //data from database
    setdata(response.data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      functioncalhttp();
    },[]);

    return (
      <div>{<dataComponent callbackfunction={data}/>}</div>
    )
 }
```

Compnent 2:

```
  import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
  export default function dataComponent(props) {

    console.log(props.callbackfunction);

    return (
      <div></div>
    )

  }
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What's the value of 'data' in the `Parentcomponent`? I think this might be a timing issue where data is not set prior to being passed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429201/2958996

Comment: the data is coming from database. On my example callbackfunction={data}, the value of data need to pass on the dataComponent. Yes it pass successfully but when I console log the data they have 2 or 3 empty string in the console log before the actual string data.

Comment: The render function can actually get called a few times before react ever paints to the screen, perhaps the child component is also getting re-rendered a couple times so it is seeing both states from the parent.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. they render few times and that's my problem. I couldn't get the data once.

Comment: So are you asking how to make react render less?  Stifle unnecessary renders?

Comment: No. I know it runs subsequent render. I'm confused only on how i could pass this data once. Is that possible?

Comment: It is a prop, it will get passed every time that component renders.  Do you want the child to only mount when the data is actually ready to render?

Comment: Yes. how could I mount the child component when data is actually ready to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the core of react is the idea of rendering components when either its state or received props change. Props are always passed to components when they render, so here in your case, whenever `data` changes, the child component will receive your new `data` state on the `callbackfunction` prop, and rerender. If you want to "wait" to render children until data is ready, here is a demo using a guard pattern to include children when conditions are met:

[image: Edit nervous-aryabhata-5uzff]

React also provides a way to further hint to react when a component should rerender with a `memo` HOC that provides more control over the received props and selectively letting react know that a rerender isn't necessary.