# Delayed invocation useEffect causes inconsistencies of component model

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When dependencies of `useEffect` hook change, the effect function of the `useEffect` hook being invoked only *after* the render cycle ([more discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424405/does-a-render-happen-before-function-in-react-hooks-useeffect-is-called/55429201#55429201)). This frequently creates situations when UI become inconsistent due to inconsistency in the component model.

Here is a simple example where `useEffect` used to run computation of `resultValue` based on value of `inputValue`:

```js
function App() {
  const [inputValue, incrementInputValue] = useReducer((s, _) => s + 1, 0);
  const [resultValue, setResultValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // It could be an asynchronous call to business logic etc.
    setResultValue(inputValue * 2);
  }, [inputValue]);

  console.log("Render: %d * 2 = %d", inputValue, resultValue);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{inputValue} * 2 = {resultValue}</p>
      <button onClick={() => { console.log('Click'); incrementInputValue(undefined); }}>
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code returns the following log:

```
Render: 0 * 2 = 0
Click 
Render: 1 * 2 = 0 // inputValue was updated, but useEffect not called yet
Render: 1 * 2 = 2
Click 
Render: 2 * 2 = 2 // inputValue was updated, but useEffect not called yet
Render: 2 * 2 = 4
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bohr-jbhh0)

What would be the best approach to avoid such inconsistencies caused by delayed invocation of useEffect?

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire lifecycle that runs after dispatching an action (`incrementInputValue`), you won't make it consistent without "removing" this lifecycle:

1. Clicking a button.
2. Dispatching an action (`incrementInputValue`)
3. Re-rendering duo to a state change (`inputValue`)
4. Running `useEffect` callback duo to `inputValue` change.
5. Re-rendering duo to a state change (`resultValue`)

Therefore as said, you need to get rid of phase `3`.

There are some solutions, you can use a reference, or combine it within a single state.

```
const reducer = (state, increase) => ({
  inputValue: state.inputValue + increase,
  resultValue: state.resultValue + increase * 2
});

const initial = { inputValue: 0, resultValue: 0 };

function App() {
  const [state, increaseResult] = useReducer(reducer, initial);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        {state.inputValue} * 2 = {state.resultValue}
      </p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log('Click');
          increaseResult(1);
        }}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> What is the best approach? It depends on the use case, its more a question of when and why using a reference instead of the state.
>
> In this particular example one can argue that you can derive all logic with just division: `inputValue = resultValue / 2`.

[image: Edit gifted-poitras-3bng4]