# In a custom-hook why return happens before of useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider this common famous hook

```
// Copied from https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/
// License is Unlicensed, https://github.com/gragland/usehooks/blob/master/LICENSE
function usePrevious<T>(value: T): T | undefined {
  // The ref object is a generic container whose current property is mutable ...
  // ... and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class
  const ref = React.useRef<T>();

  // Store current value in ref
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); // Only re-run if value changes

  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)
  return ref.current;
}
```

Why are we sure that the useEffect above the return value runs after returning the ref and giving us therefore the old value?

Comment: Because `useEffect()` runs _after_ every render, according to the documentation. In this case, because `[value]` is the `deps`, it runs only after every render where the reference for `value` changes.

Comment: possible duplication - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424405/does-a-render-happen-before-function-in-react-hooks-useeffect-is-called/55424674

Comment: Hope so this approach will help you!! create state object e.g 
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); 
have a check on  component return like

 if (isLoading) {
        return (
        <View> <Text> Loading...</Text> </View>
        )
    }
/// your main return
return (/// your code)


use setIsLoading(false) after the result/function your are waiting to complete.

Hope so it will help you.