# Getting undefined error on accessing JSON object in react - OpenWeatherAPI

Tags: reactjs

I am using OpenWeatherMapAPI to fetch current weather (API keys are hidden).
The idea is to fetch the value and pass it as props to render in a different component.
I have tried a few ways but unable to display value from the response.

The response is valid as I have checked it on jsonlint.

I am getting an undefined error.

```
const [city, setCity] = useState();
  let currentWeather;

  {
    // UseEffect to run the effect during initial render
    useEffect(() => {
      
        axios
          .get(baseUrl + city + ",IN&APPID=" + APPKey + "&units=metric")
          .then((res) => {
            currentWeather = res.data;
          });
      
      // fetch(baseUrl + city + ",IN&APPID=" + APPKey + "&units=metric");
    }, []);
  }

  const handleInputChanges = (e) => {
    setCity(e.target.value);
  };

  const resetSearchValue = () => {
    setCity("");
  };

  const fetchWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    {
      {
        axios
          .get(baseUrl + city + ",IN&APPID=" + APPKey + "&units=metric")
          .then((res) => {
            currentWeather = res.data;
            console.log("weather", currentWeather);
          });
      }
    }

    resetSearchValue();
  };

  return (
    <Container className="themed-container" fluid="sm">
      <InputGroup className="search">
        <Input
          placeholder="Enter a city in India"
          value={city}
          onChange={handleInputChanges}
        />
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={fetchWeather}>
            Check
          </Button>
        </InputGroupAddon>
        // for testing the output
        <h1>{currentWeather.sys.country}</h1>
      </InputGroup>
      //the object wil be passed as props to other component for rendering the
      result
      <FetchWeather search={currentWeather} />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Searchbar;
```

OpenWeatherAPI Response

```
    JSON : {"coord":{"lon":77.6,"lat":12.98},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":297.51,"feels_like":301.13,"temp_min":295.15,"temp_max":302.04,"pressure":1010,"humidity":100},"visibility":6000,"wind":{"speed":3.45,"deg":206},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1593102591,"sys":{"type":1,"id":9205,"country":"IN","sunrise":1593044734,"sunset":1593091128},"timezone":19800,"id":1277333,"name":"Bengaluru","cod":200}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424405/does-a-render-happen-before-function-in-react-hooks-useeffect-is-called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined currentWeather as a regular javascript variable.

```
  let currentWeather;
```

This will not trigger render . Declare currentWeather as a state variable using "useState" and you should be able to see the data.

Comment: Still, I get the same error. This time sys is undefined.  If I define it as an object, the country becomes undefined.

Comment: You have to add relevant checks for the Objects. Since "sys" is a child property you have to check if  currentWeather object exists and only then display currentWeather.sys.***   ..  like this -  <h1>{currentWeather && currentWeather.sys && currentWeather.sys.country}</h1>

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working. I somehow don't understand why do we need to have a check if the response is successful. If there is a big size response with multiple nested elements, there will be a lot of checks.