# Why am I getting extra re-renders in this component?

Tags: reactjs

Why am I getting extra re-renders inside this component I just can't find out why? this problem is caused within the component and not caused by a parent. Every time state changes it shows twice in the console "Inside preview container"
I even used `useRef()` inside `useEffect()` to compare old values with current ones and it showed twice
files undefined then files `{ image: "", video: "", name: "", render: false, hideImage: true }`

```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import "./PreviewContainer.scss";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
    function PreviewContainer(props) {
      console.log("Inside Preview Container");
      const [files, setFiles] = useState({ image: "", video: "", name: "", render: false, hideImage: true });
      const [muted, setMuted] = useState(true);
      let history = props.history;
      let insideMovie = props.insideMovie;
      let formData = props.formData;
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("inside useEffect");
        axios.post("http://localhost/netflix/index.php", formData).then((response) => {
          if (response.data) {
            let movie;
            if (insideMovie) {
              movie = JSON.parse(response.data.movie);
            } else movie = response.data;
            setFiles({
              hideImage: true,
              image: movie.image.split("/")[2],
              video: movie.video.split("/")[2],
              name: movie.name,
              render: true,
            });
          } else {
            history.push("/404");
          }
        });
      }, [formData, insideMovie, history]);
    
      const muteToggle = () => {
        setMuted(!muted);
      };
      const showImage = () => {
        setFiles({ ...files, hideImage: false });
      };
      return (
        <div className="preview-container">
          {files.render ? (
            <>
              <img
                className="preview-image"
                alt={files.name}
                src={require(`../../assets/entities/thumbnails/${files.image}`)}
                hidden={files.hideImage}
              ></img>
    
              <video onEnded={showImage} className="preview-video" muted={muted} autoPlay hidden={!files.hideImage}>
                <source src={require(`../../assets/entities/previews/${files.video}`)} type="video/mp4"></source>
              </video>
            </>
          ) : null}
    
          <div className="preview-overlay">
            <div className="mainDetails">
              <h3>{files.name}</h3>
    
              <div className="video-controls">
                <button>
                  <i className="fas fa-play"></i> Play
                </button>
                <button onClick={muteToggle}>{muted ? <i className="fas fa-volume-mute"></i> : <i className="fas fa-volume-up"></i>}</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default withRouter(PreviewContainer);
```

Comment: `useEffect` will fire *everytime* the variables inside your dependency array change (in your case, `formData`, `insideMovie`, `history`. If you want it to fire once, simply leave the dependency array empty `[]`

Comment: @DavidBuzatu the problem not fixed, by the way the code inside useEffect is executed only once anyway

Comment: @DavidBuzatu I mean even if I leave [] the extra re-renders are still happening

Comment: are you sure it happens every time the state is being changed, not only for the very first one?

Comment: @Tarukami I think yes because on the button where I change the muted state only it causes a double re-render

Comment: Are you sure your `formData` does not change twice? It's the only thing I would look into right now. I see that it comes as `props` and it might be changing, triggering your `useEffect` twice

Comment: @DavidBuzatu I checked it and props don't change at all also the console.log("Inside useEffect) is executed only once

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want your `useEffect` to act as a `componentDidMount`, meaning that you only want one render, you should leave the dependency array empty:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //...work
}, []);
```

Then, if you log something in your component, it will get logged and *then* call your effect, resulting in 2 logs. Based on this comprehensive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429201/11023871), React will render your component and then call the `useEffect()`. This is why it is not recommended to log something directly inside your React component body (use a function instead).

Comment: if I remove the dependencies from the array I get this warning
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'formData', 'history', and 'insideMovie'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.
For the first time it's true it should show 2 console.log() but every time state is changed even the useEffect isn't executed again 2 console.log() are shown again, I don't think this has to do with useEffect because for the first time the console.log() inside useEffect is executed but other times only console.log() outside useEffect() is executed twice and inside the useEffect isn't.

Comment: and even if I ignore the warning and leave just [] it still shows console.log() twice on every state change.

Comment: This is the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) about `useEffect` and empty dependency. I guess it triggers twice because:
1. On every render, you log your message.
2. When you get to render, you set the state in `showImage` and that fires a re-render again => 2 logs.

Comment: there are 6 console.logs in total even if I change only the muted state it display 2 console.logs()